# Disable All Math Mode Printing in PDF

Tags: math-mode

My LaTeX documents have numerous equations and math-mode symbols using notation `$...$`, `equation`, and `align`.  To assist with grammar and language issues, I run my compiled PDFs through Grammarly by first converting the PDF to a Google doc.

The PDF -> Google Doc -> Grammarly process always has issues with the equations/symbols.  Disabling printing of math-mode symbols would make integration with Grammarly significantly better.  Is it possible to (easily) disable all math printing in a LaTeX document without (significantly) changing the equations themselves?  My document has hundreds or thousands of equations and changing each is not practical at this stage.

My hope would be nothing or a blank space would be inserted where the math-mode symbols/equations would be.